# My compare to local history no longer works

Tags: eclipse

every time I left click on a file name and select compare with local history, I get a dialog box that says the following
"No local history available for selected item"
I tried

```
1. creating new project
2. creating new work space
```

Don't know what else to do

Comment: Are you talking about local git history or what? What does this question have to do with java?

Comment: It sounds like you are using an IDE? But you don't even specify which one

Comment: I've edited to add the tag `eclipse`. I could be wrong. Please use the correct tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new project or workspace there won't be any local history.

In Eclipse local history for a file is kept for a few days and is then deleted. So if you have not edited something for a while there will not be any local history for the file.

You can configure how long the history is kept in the Preferences in 'General > Workspace > Local History'